# C3: Adding y2 axis on the fly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I know that I can create additional Y axis by using the `c3.generate(...)` as shown [in this example](http://c3js.org/samples/axes_y2.html).

My question is: can I achieve the same in another moment (e.g. on a click event)?

My application already uses user inputs (e.g. clicks) to dynamically add new columns, by directly by using the `load()` function and providing the data series (without using `generate`).

Does something similar exist for dynamically showing other Y axis?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the column which are used as reference for the axis, then you can just load it with the `load()` function:

```
chart.load({
   axis:{
     colA:'y',
     colB: 'y2
   }
})
```

When you want to switch the visibility of the y2 axis, then you cannot use the load function since it has only limited access (see [reference](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load) at the API-part).

The only way I see is manipulating the chart configuration on the fly by using `chart.internal.config`, you can just give it a try.